# React facebook login doesn't work at all - What am I missing?

Tags: reactjs, facebook-login

Im trying to include react Facebook login and am doing it exactly as describes in face books documentation (https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login) but keep getting strange errors. Im new to react and have been looking at my code since so long but just don't know what Im doing wrong since Im doing exactly whats described in their documentation. Any help would be so so much appreciated!! Thanks!

error: unexpected token for const responseFacebook:

```
            import React from 'react';
            import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
            import  FacebookLogin  from 'react-facebook-login';

            class Login extends React.Component{             
              constructor (props, context) {
                super(props, context);
              }

             const responseFacebook = (response) => {
              console.log(response);
            }

              render () {
                return (
                  <div>
                   <FacebookLogin
                    appId="1112xxx"
                    autoLoad={true}
                    fields="name,email,picture"
                    onClick={componentClicked}
                    callback={this.responseFacebook} />
                  </div>
                );
              }

            }

            export default Login;
```

changing the responseFacebook function to :

```
  constructor (props, context) {
        super(props, context);
         this.responseFacebook=responseFacebook.this.bind(this);
      }
    responseFacebook (response){
      console.log(response);
    }
```

gives me this error: responseFacebook is not defined

update (with still not working code):

```
        import React from 'react';
        import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
        import  FacebookLogin  from 'react-facebook-login';

        class Login extends React.Component{

                  constructor (props, context) {
                    super(props, context);
                     this.responseFacebook=responseFacebook.this.bind(this);
                  }


                responseFacebook = (response) => {
                     console.log(response);
                }

          render () {
            return (
              <div>
               <FacebookLogin
            appId="1112954322170315"
            autoLoad={true}
            fields="name,email,picture"
            onClick={componentClicked}
            callback={this.responseFacebook} />

              </div>
            );
          }

        }

        export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this;

```
const responseFacebook = (response) => {
    console.log(response);
}
```

To this;

```
responseFacebook = (response) => {
    console.log(response);
}
```

or you do this

```
responseFacebook(response) {
    console.log(response);
}

render () {
    return (
        <div>
            <FacebookLogin
                appId="1112xxx"
                autoLoad={true}
                fields="name,email,picture"
                onClick={componentClicked}
                callback={this.responseFacebook.bind(this)} 
            />
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried both but for the first one, Im still getting 'unexpected token' (now it tells me the '=' sign is the unexpected token responseFacebook = ) and for the second solution Im still getting responseFacebook is not defined..

Comment: can you update your answer with the last version of your code please

Comment: I updated it. I also tried to write it like that:  responseFacebook (response) { console.log(response);} which doesn't throw me an error at this point, but then im getting the error: 'responseFacebook is not defined'

Comment: you don't need to bind `this` since you are using arrow functions. You can remove `this.responseFacebook=responseFacebook.this.bind(this);` also it is written wrong. It has to be like this `this.responseFacebook=this.responseFacebook.bind(this);`

Comment: I was binding this when I was not using the error function and yes you are right it was written wrong. So the error function from the documentation still shows me an error, but since I rewrote it to: this.responseFacebook=this.responseFacebook.bind(this) the responseFacebook function seems to be fine but now I am getting a new error: 'componentClicked is not defined'

Comment: because you don't have a componentClicked method but you try to run it onClick. I suggest you to do a little bit more reading about react before you continue.

Comment: Im just confused what that react-facebook-login is for exactly, if its not doing anything. The error function is throwing me errors, now I commented out the onClick just to see what happens and now im getting the error Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined

Comment: react-facebook-login is for easily integrating facebook login to a react app. you don't need to use onClick prop. Its an optional prop. you just need to deal with the response from the facebook and use it for your apps authentication. And if you get a new error please post it completely so we can help much easily

Comment: hmm okay, then react-facebook-login is simply not working. I have nothing knew to post (didn't change my code) just getting that new error when I remove the onClick property

Answer (score 0):

I also had lots of problems with react-facebook-login. I tried [this](https://dev.to/quod_ai/how-to-integrate-facebook-login-api-into-your-react-app-33de) and
[this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ins-7Ze29IQ) tutorials, but all the time got `n.props.callback is not a function` error. Then [this](https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login/issues/246) and current thread lead me to test Class components with binding, but also no result.

Finally I found that I installed react-facebook-login worng way.

Don't do

```
npm install react-facebook-login --force
```

Instead do

```
npm install react-facebook-login --legacy-peer-deps
```